# Not including exact words and tags in regular expression to get date

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex and the re python module.

I trying to just capture the date from the following code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <strong>
                    Date:
                </strong>
            December 18th 2015 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I have the regular expression:

```
(((?!Date:)(?!\n)(.+)(<\/strong\>)(\n)(.+))(\S))
```

But it still gets back all of:

```
                </strong>
            December 20th 2016
```

I want to ditch the  and whitespace and just get "December 20th 2016"

So I need to do something with the bit of the regular expression after (((?!Date:)(?!\n), i.e. this bit needs to change:

```
(.+)(<\/strong\>)(\n)(.+))(\S))
```

But I'm not sure what as I can't do negative lookahead (?!) with the .+ according to regexr.com

Any ideas to get back just "December 20th 2016"?

Comment: Why would you use regex for this? Why not use an HTML parser?

Comment: Because I want to learn how to do it with regexr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
?:
```

at the beginning of some groups means they are non-capturing group, that's what you need to use to avoid capturing unwanted stuff.

However, as Daniel Roseman said, you should probably use an HTML parser

Edit:

```
from re import findall
s = """        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <strong>
                    Date:
                </strong>
            December 18th 2015 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>"""
res = findall(r'(?:Date:)(?:\n)(?:.+)(?:\n)(?:\s+)(.+)', s)
print(res)
```

This prints ['December 18th 2015 '] ( python 3.5.2)

Comment: (?:Date:)(?:\n)(?:.+)(?:\n)(?:\s+)(.+)

Comment: This still retrieves the earlier stuff. I know I could use one, but I am not using a parser because I'm trying to learn how to use re.

Comment: The shorter version (?:Date:\n.+\n\s+)(.+) also fails, it selects everything from 'Date:' to the actual date I want.